# Необработанные строковые литералы

Tags: c++, c++11

Для чего нужны необработанные строковые литералы (`raw string literals`)? В каких случаях стоит их применять?

Comment: Чтобы избавиться от [Leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), конечно.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Чтобы ASCII арты выводить проще было:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<
        R"xxx(       \     (      /
   `.    \     )    /    .'
     `.   \   (    /   .'
       `.  .-''''-.  .'
 `~._    .'/_    _\`.    _.~'
     `~ /  / \  / \  \ ~'
_ _ _ _|  _\O/  \O/_  |_ _ _ _
       | (_)  /\  (_) |
    _.~ \  \      /  / ~._
 .~'     `. `.__.' .'     `~.
       .'  `-,,,,-'  `.
     .'   /    )   \   `.
   .'    /    (     \    `.
        /      )     \     hjw
              ()xxx";
}
```

Ну и для регулярных выражений, конечно, но ascii арты, безусловно, важнее.

Comment: Разумеется, ASCII-art! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420909/10105

Answer (score 3):

Мое мнение - для упрощения записи. Когда приходится иметь дело с, например, регулярными выражениями, запутаться во всех обратных косых чертах - раз плюнуть. Вот в этой ситуации проще обойтись таким литералом. Какое-нибудь `R"(\w{2}\s*\d{5}\\(-\d{4}\))"` проще читать и писать, чем `\\w{2}\\s*\\d{5}\\\\(-\\d{4}\\)`...