# Избежать экранирования закрывающей кавычки С++

Tags: c++, строки, экранирование

При попытке создания строкового литерала

```
"C:\"
```

закрывающая кавычка экранируется, чего нужно избежать.

Comment: А вы обратный слеш экранируйте, тогда кавычка экранироваться не будет.

Comment: `"C:\\"` - вот так. `'\\'` - символ обратного слэша.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ты экранируешь кавычки, а нужно экранировать слэш. 
Заменить так

```
 "C:\\"
```

или

```
 "C:/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё вариант использования сырых строковых литералов (`C++11`) для исключения экранирований:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* s = R"(C:\)";
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

> C:\

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ojlcvZOTm5lANzd2)</kbd>

Comment: в них офигенно удобно json запихивать для тестов

Comment: @strangeqargo и не [только](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513929/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b).